# Which adjectives can describe 'intellect' and 'education'?

Tags: phrasing

I use 'great' too many times, I would need something more lively and original. I have a sentence like this:

*In order to acquire this, one does not need a **great** intellect, nor a ... education*
Thank you!

Comment: Super-intellect; https://www.lexico.com/definition/superintelligent; and from the usage 'highly educated', I think high education should also sound OK. May be, others can say better ones.

Comment: super-intellect is a bit colloquial for the language register I need. But high education is a good idea. Thanks a lot!

Comment: A [***strong** intellect*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=great+intellect%2Cstrong+intellect&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgreat%20intellect%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstrong%20intellect%3B%2Cc0) is a fairly common collocation. But this is essentially Off Topic "writing advice". Note that "strong intellect" doesn't necessarily imply "well-educated".

Comment: Thank you, I like 'strong intellect'. The fact that I juxtapose 'strong intellect' and 'high (now I am tempted to put 'good') education' does not necessarily imply that they are synonyms does it... so now my sentence looks like that: _In order to acquire this, one does not need a strong intellect, nor a good education._

Comment: Agree with FF (writing advice, also lack of research shown). But 'In order to acquire this, one does not need a vast / formidable intellect, nor a private / university / first-class /  an excellent education (assuming attributive nouns are not for some reason inadmissible).

Comment: @FF: could you direct me where I should look to understand what is _on_ and _off_ topic on this site, it is not always clear to me. Is not word choice a proper tag?

Comment: @Edwin: Good suggestions. How can I find out some guiding lines about is off topic here?

Comment: 'Something more lively and original'  is a request for style guidance, not grammaticality, the meaning of a particular word or string in context, punctuation etc. Answers would be almost necessarily subjective.  'A word meaning envy but without the "malice" component' would be more suitable, but should be accompanied by references to lists of synonyms (in thesauri, say), showing what didn't (or did!) work. The Help Center gives essential guidance.

Comment: Regarding what is on-topic and off-topic here, have a look at the “Asking” entries at the link: [help].

Comment: Choose your metaphor. Is intellect one-dimensional, two-dimensional, or three-dimensional? Is it a muscle? Is it a machine? Is it a thing or is it alive? Since _intellect_ is entirely imaginary, in the sense that  the word has no ostensive meaning, any adjective used to describe it is gonna be metaphorical. If you want to have some effect with your words, choose your metaphors carefully and employ them consistently and strategically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In order to acquire this, one does not need a **A** intellect, nor a **B** education

**A**) powerful, strong, mighty, sharp

**B**) college, tertiary, academic, advanced, broad

Answer (score 2):

you could say "higher intellect and superior education." Your sentence could look like this: In order to acquire this, one does not need a superior intellect, nor higher education.

Comment: Yeah, "superior" works for both.

Answer (score 1):

One strategy for adding originality to your adjective selection is to choose one that pertains to the quality that you're evoking. **Great** can attach to so many nouns and noun phrases. More verbose versions of **great** (like **excellent**) are more emphatic but no more specific. However, a word like **sagacious** pertains specifically to discernment:

> 2.a. Gifted with acuteness of mental discernment; having special aptitude for the discovery of truth; penetrating and judicious in the estimation of character and motives, and in the devising of means for the accomplishment of ends; shrewd. ([OED](https://oed.com/view/Entry/169717))

So someone who has a **sagacious intellect** is shrewd and can likely plan out a large project. They are not likely to be fooled by appearances.

Whether that word works or not, you can use a search strategy of going between synonyms and near-synonyms in a thesaurus, seeking adjectives specific to mental faculties, in order to find the precise emphasis you want.

Answer (score 1):

Consider ***incisive*** for *intellect* and ***extensive*** for *education*, as in:

> ... one does not need an ***incisive*** intellect, nor an ***extensive*** education

I personally like these choices for their alliteration. Examples of their usage in the wild below:

---

> He embarked on a 90-minute discourse that showcased his ***incisive intellect***, his rambling imagination, and his almost pathological attention to detail.
> <sub>[LA Times](https://www.latimes.com/science/sciencenow/la-sci-sn-buzz-aldrin-earth-to-echo-20140709-story.html)</sub>

---

> Even to work in museum as a guide requires ***extensive education*** and training.
> <sub>[NY Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2001/05/20/nyregion/what-i-did-for-others-on-my-summer-vacation.html)</sub>

---

Answer (score 0):

[**"brilliant"**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/brilliant) seems like a good fit.
(*one does not need a brilliant education*)

> - outstanding, exceptional, splendid, magnificent: having or showing unusual and impressive intelligence: **a brilliant mind**; a brilliant solution to the problem.

. Bertrand Russell had a brilliant mind.

. Mozart showed his brilliance at an early age.

. To leave half and hour earlier was a brilliant idea.

.  "the defective moral training of many persons in the upper classes who have had **a brilliant education**".[**¹**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=kZwEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA616&dq=%22a+brilliant+education%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwii8MSS1sHtAhVYILkGHSkoCtsQ6AEwBXoECAcQAg)

. "From 1833 to 1840 she received **a brilliant education** according to the ideas of the bourgeoisie." [**²**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=bLHoDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT6936&dq=%22a+brilliant+education%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwii8MSS1sHtAhVYILkGHSkoCtsQ6AEwB3oECAgQAg)

Comment: You know, I actually like more _**impressive**_ than anything that has been said here... Would _brilliant_ apply to education?